# Taylor diagrams in R

Tags: r, plotrix

I have not used plotrix before but I am trying to create a taylor diagram to show the SD and RMS errors between reanalysis wind speed data and modelled wind speed projections from RCM RCA4 forced by 5 different GCM.

The script I am using can be seen below (edited: reproducible data now in place). I am not sure what I am doing wrong but as you can see from the attached image multiple points are being plotted for each modelled dataset, rather than a singular point...[Taylor diagram test plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx3BO.png)

Any advice or guidance on what I am doing wrong and how to correct it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```html
library(datasets)
library(ncdf4)
library(plotrix)



data <- volcano

taylor.diagram(volcano,volcano,add=FALSE,col="red",pch=4,pos.cor=TRUE,xlab="MERRA SD (Normalised)",ylab="RCA4 runs SD (normalised)",main="Taylor Diagram",show.gamma=TRUE,ngamma=3,sd.arcs=1,ref.sd=TRUE,grad.corr.lines=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9),pcex=1,cex.axis=1,normalize=TRUE,mar=c(5,4,6,6),lwd=10,font=5,lty=3)

lpos<-1.5*sd(windMERRA)

legend(1.5,1.5,cex=1.2,pt.cex=1.2,legend=c("volcano"),pch=4,col=c("red"))
```

Comment: Please use reproducible data for your example

Comment: Sorry I am very much a beginner in R and am not sure how to do that....maybe a better question for me to ask would be what format my data should be in to input into taylor.diagram function?

Comment: May first timers make that mistake. But with either question, they'll close/downvote your question if you don't provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would just take a little extra time to go find some reproducible data you can use with your question and re-write it. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  It's to help us help you.

Comment: Okay thanks, I will give that a go!

Answer (score 2):

The `volcano` dataset is a matrix. The `taylor.diagram()` expects a vector of values for `ref` and `model` arguments. Using matrices in the function seems to result in more than one point per column of the matrix, but I am not sure exactly what it does. Check the format of your data. If it is in matrices, then you can use `as.vector()` to convert them into vectors and use these vectors in `taylor.diagram()` and use 'add=TRUE' after plotting the first dataset. The example for a single point with `volcano` is given below..

[image]

```
library(datasets)
library(ncdf4)
library(plotrix)

taylor.diagram(as.vector(volcano), # makes a vector
               as.vector(volcano), # makes a vector
               add=FALSE,
               col="red",
               pch=4,
               pos.cor=TRUE,
               xlab="MERRA SD (Normalised)",
               ylab="RCA4 runs SD (normalised)",
               main="Taylor Diagram",
               show.gamma=TRUE,
               ngamma=3,
               sd.arcs=1,
               ref.sd=TRUE,
               grad.corr.lines=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9),
               pcex=1,cex.axis=1,
               normalize=TRUE,
               mar=c(5,4,6,6),
               lwd=10,
               font=5,
               lty=3)

taylor.diagram(as.vector(volcano),
               as.vector(volcano),
               add=FALSE,
               col="red",
               pch=4,
               pos.cor=TRUE,
               xlab="MERRA SD (Normalised)",
               ylab="RCA4 runs SD (normalised)",
               main="Taylor Diagram",
               show.gamma=TRUE,
               ngamma=3,
               sd.arcs=1,
               ref.sd=TRUE,
               grad.corr.lines=c(0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9),
               pcex=1,cex.axis=1,
               normalize=TRUE,
               mar=c(5,4,6,6),
               lwd=10,
               font=5,
               lty=3)

legend(1.5,1.5,cex=1.2,pt.cex=1.2,legend=c("volcano"),pch=4,col=c("red"))
```